# Android studio - String htmlText как вывести локальные данные из assets?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Пытаюсь нарисовать в `WebView` страничку. Но в String htmlText никак не получается положить ссылки на локальные страницы. Может кто знает как это сделать?

Хочется чтобы в String htmlText можно было ссылаться на файлы которые лежат в assets

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String htmlText = "<html><body>Percent test: 100% <a href='file:///android_asset/biatlon.html'>link</a></body></html>";
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadData(htmlText, "text/html", "utf-8");
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Что вы не можете прочитать данные файле из assets?

Comment: На выходе появляется текст из строки "htmlText", но ссылка <a href='file:///android_asset/biatlon.html'>link</a> не ведет на файл biatlon.html, так же если <img src="file:///android_asset/1.jpg"> указать в строке htmlText, то не появляется картинка. Вот в этом проблема

Comment: WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
String htmlText = "<html><body>Percent test: 100% <a href='biatlon.html'>link</a></body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlText, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

Comment: Спасибо дружище, реально выручил, респект, молодец!